# Why does cd failure in sh end the run early, bash doesn't

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm migrating shell scripts from solaris to redhat, using sh in solaris and bash in redhat.
Run `cd /notexistsdir; echo 123` on both machines.
When the cd command reports an error in sh, it will not print 123, but in bash, it will print 123 after the cd command reports an error, indicating that the cd failure in sh will end the operation.
I tried to run `cp /notexistsfile /aaa; echo 123` in sh again, although the cp command reported an error, it would print 123, and it did not end the operation.
i want to ask

1. What other commands in sh will end running after execution fails?
2. Why do sh and bash handle cd failure differently?
   (using man cd to check the documentation, also found no information about the failure of the cd execution)

Comment: What does `set -o` in `sh` print?

Comment: The default is for the shell to continue after errors, unless the `-e` option is set. I'm not sure what shell Solaris has as sh, but it'd be really weird for it to exit without specifically having the `-e` option set. BTW, even with `-e` set, the shell may not exit when you expect (and/or may exit when you *don't* expect); see [BashFAQ #105: "Why doesn't `set -e` (or `set -o errexit`, or `trap ERR`) do what I expected?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Comment: @Biffen
I created a new user test in solaris, this is the test information.
`$ cat .profile`

`#       This is the default standard profile provided to a user.`
`#       They are expected to edit it to meet their own needs.`

`MAIL=/usr/mail/${LOGNAME:?}`

`$ echo $SHELL`
`/usr/bin/sh`

`$ cd /notexistsdir;echo 123`

`/notexistsdir: does not exist.`
`$`

Comment: Do you run the command `cd /notexistsdir; echo 123` directly from command line, or inside a script? What's the output of `type cd` ?

Comment: @M. Nejat Aydin
i’m run the command in commandline,`type cd` output `cd is a shell builtin`.
I wrote a script that reads `#!/bin/sh
cd /notexistsdir
echo 123`
also not print 123 :(

Comment: @GordonDavisson  
I created a new user to test this problem. The user's shell is /usr/bin/sh, and set -e and set -o are not used (using set -o in the sh profile will prompt that the o option is invalid), still it will not print 123

Comment: As far as I know, the shell used by Solaris is not a POSIX-compliant shell. Without knowing what shell it *is*, it's useless to speculate about its specific differences with `bash`. (I've seen references that indicate it is the actual, original Bourne shell, but I cannot confirm.)

Answer (score -1):

In bash, `cd /notexistsdir && echo 123` should omit the `123` if `cd` produced an error.

Alternatively, you can call bash so that it fails on error. That would be done with `bash -e`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if this is indeed a feature of sh, I can only modify the code :(